# post data to an external url in php

Tags: php, drupal, salesforce

I have a php file like this (HTML code is generated by web to lead from salesforce) :

```
<?php
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
?>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D200000000WlM">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL"    value="http://www.listertechnologies.com/contact-us">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><em>*</em><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required/><br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><em>*</em><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required/><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label><em>*</em><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required/><br>
    <label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    Please select nature of enquiry:<em>*</em><select  id="00ND0000006U5Eo" name="00ND0000006U5Eo" title="Please select nature of enquiry" required>
        <option value="">--None--</option><option value="I need a solution">I need a solution</option>
        <option value="I have a question">I have a question</option>
        <option value="I am looking for a career opportunity">I am looking for a   career opportunity</option>
    </select><br>

    Message:<textarea  id="00ND0000006U5Et" name="00ND0000006U5Et" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

I want to process some logic before sending it to salesforce. Like if it is career (one option in dropdown) then dont submit to salesforce just send mail to some department. I am new to php any help will be apprerciated,

Comment: please ask if you need any details

Comment: Like you said if its a career then send mail and if not send to salesforce. So, you need to create a php file and in that file you can create some if condition for mailing and salesforce.

Comment: yeah.. but how can i send the form  data to salesforce from php? any code snippet will help. as i am new to php and i have a very short deadline.

Comment: check this out for sending data to salesforce. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38841/sending-data-from-php-to-salesforce-using-curl and this one too. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008sG0IAI